# Confusion about ROS sourcing

Tags: ros, ros2, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've read many answers about how ROS sourcing works and I'm a bit confused on a couple things:

#### Can you source an overlay before building it?

[This](https://answers.ros.org/question/206876/how-often-do-i-need-to-source-setupbash/?answer=206878#post-id-206878) answer says you can add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

However, the [ROS2 tutorials](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace/#source-the-overlay) say the following:

> Before sourcing the overlay (your
> workspace), it is very important that
> you open a new terminal, separate from
> the one where you built the workspace.
> Sourcing an overlay in the same
> terminal where you built, or likewise
> building where an overlay is sourced,
> may create complex issues.

The first answer results in your overlay always being sourced every time you open a terminal. This contradicts the ROS2 tutorial that says you shouldn't source the overlay before building it.

#### Why do you need to source both `/opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash` and `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`?

I looked at the environment variables with `printenv` when I sourced both of them vs. just the latter and they were the same. It seems like you only need to source `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` given that you have sourced `/opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash` before running `catkin_make`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371227/confusion-about-ros-sourcing/) by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 1 and ROS 2 cannot necessarily be compared when it comes to environment setup. So whatever you read for ROS 1, does not necessarily translate to ROS 2.

re: why `source` both: you don't need to. It's a pattern I see often mentioned, but it's not needed.

Having those two lines in your `.bashrc` does provide some convenience though: *if* `$HOME/catkin_ws` exists and has been built, it will result in that workspace getting `source`d. If it doesn't, you'll at least get the base ROS environment `source`d.

So I guess it's more about convenience than necessity.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-07**:
Thanks so much for clearing that up! As a small follow-up, is there any detriment to sourcing multiple workspaces with --extend in your .bashrc (ex. `source ~/catkin_ws && source ~/other_ws --extend`)? This seems like it would let you access packages from both workspaces, but I'm not sure if there's any reason not to do this

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-07**:
It's not a good idea to ask follow-up questions as comments under questions with accepted answers. They have very little visibility.

It would be better to post a new question -- after having made sure there isn't already a question about the same topic of course (use Google: add `site:answers.ros.org` to your query).

**Comment by [EricW](https://answers.ros.org/users/62918/ericw/) on 2021-02-07**:
Got it. Thanks for the help! Found a good answer [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying). I had read it before, but coming back to it fresh, it made a lot more sense